# Is there a way to detect the exception in dispose?

Tags: c#

I have the following scenario:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            using (new Foo())
            {
                throw new Exception("Inside using block");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
}

public class Foo : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new Exception("Inside dispose");
    }
}
```

Is it somehow possible, to get the thrown exception - `"Inside using block"` - in the `Dispose` method of `Foo` and make it an `InnerException` of the `Exception` `Inside dispose`?

**Edit:**

For example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var fi = new FileHandler())
            {
                //open the file
                fi.Open();

                //write to the file
                fi.Write();

                //excption occurs
                throw new Exception("Inside using block");

                fi.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //now I only have the exception from the dispose but not the exception that occured in the using block itself
            //I know I could wrap the code inside the using in a try/catch itself, just asking if it is possible without 2 try/catches
        }
    }
}

public class FileHandler : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        //Close the file
        //for some reason it fails with an exception
        throw new Exception("Inside dispose");
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? This sounds like an X-Y problem.

Comment: No, how would that work?

Comment: does yr catch in main get the exception from dispose?

Comment: Per the Framework Design Guidelines (Cwalina, Abrams), section 9.3:  "AVOID throwing an exception from within `Dispose(bool)` except under critical situations where the containing process has been corrupted... If `Dispose` could raise an exception, further finally block cleanup logic will not execute.  To work around this, the user would need to wrap every call to `Dispose` (within their finally block!) in a try block, which leads to very complex cleanup handlers.  If executing a `Dispose(bool)` method, never throw an exception if `disposing` is false."

Comment: @Amy If this was an answer I would upvote it.

Comment: @Amy I don't think the OP intends to throw in Dispose - I _think_ it's just an example of an exception happening in there. Not sure though.

Comment: @xxbbcc - yes I intended to do so

Comment: @xxbbcc - edited my question with an example

Comment: @pm100 - yes it does the exception ``inside using block`` is lost

Comment: @ZoharPeled I dont think it qualifies as an answer, does it?  I mean, OP is asking "how do i do this".  Saying "you shouldn't" doesn't exactly answer that question.  If the OP thinks its a good answer, I'll submit it as such.

Comment: @RandRandom You need to use 2 `try..catch` blocks and make note of the inner exception in a local variable to keep it around for the outside block.

Comment: @Amy definatly interessting to know, but avoidable for me since I will always use ``using`` explictly on that object and can make a deconstrutor which wont throw exception

Comment: @Amy sometimes, "Don't do that" is the best possible answer. Same thing also for "No, that's impossible". Even better when you can explain why, and best if you can provide a better way for the OP to get where they want to go.

Comment: @xxbbcc was afraid so, thought there is no mistake asking maybe some smart guy knows a way

Comment: @EdPlunkett - hoped there would be some magic :)

Comment: @RandRandom Also from section 9.3:  "AVOID making types finalizable.  Carefully consider any case in which you think a finalizer is needed.  There is a real cost associated with instances with finalizers, from both a performance and code complexity standpoint."

Comment: @RandRandom *"but avoidable for me since..."* -- you're embarking lightheartedly down a very dark road, my friend.

Comment: @Amy - really performance? I actually implement a deconstructor in 90% of the cases I inherit from ``IDisposable`` - do you know some benchmark?

Comment: @RandRandom Why do you have so many destructors? Do you work with 90% unmanaged disposable types in your code? For unmanaged resources, a destructor may be needed but for managed types / data, they're clutter and extra load for no gain.

Comment: @RandRandom If any exception might be raised by anything inside your `Dispose` method, it should be handled there and not propagate further. If it's a catastrophic exception,one that after it the application can't handle and keep going, you better let it crush.

Comment: @RandRandom yes there is a performance cost.  Just google "C# finalizers performance cost"  MSDN has a number of pages on this topic.  Finalizers should only be used if you have unmanaged resources, and even then, using `SafeHandle` is preferred.  I recommend you pick up the book, I'm referencing page 258.

Comment: @xxbbcc - I meant to say, when I use ``IDisposable`` there is a 90% chance I implemented a deconstructor. Not saying that 90% of my classes have ``IDisposable``, just saying when it does I tend to do a deconstructor.

Comment: @RandRandom That's how I understood it, too, thank you.

Comment: @Amy just to be sure, that one https://www.amazon.com/Framework-Design-Guidelines-Conventions-Libraries/dp/0321545613

Comment: @RandRandom that's it.  I think I have the 1st edition (I lost the book jacket long ago and the hardcover doesn't mention an edition), so the page numbers might be slightly off.

Comment: @Amy - if you like to you can give an answer and I will mark it as accepted

Comment: @RandRandom When you implement `IDisposable`, you should have a 0% chance of implementing a finalizer.  Maybe, if you're a Microsoft employee, it should be 0.01%.  There just aren't good reasons to use them, just about ever.

Comment: @Servy - a long time a go - dont really remember who it was - told me thats the best way to implement ``IDisposable`` - ``public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
private void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!_isDisposed)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            _isDisposing = true;
        }

        _isDisposed = true;
    }
}
~Foo()
{
    Dispose(false);
}`` - and I tend to use that "design" all the time

Comment: @RandRandom And you should stop doing that.  There is never a situation in which you're benefiting from it, and lots of situations in which it harms you.

Comment: @Servy - I am totally going to take that into account from now and I am grateful for the insight, thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the Framework Design Guidelines (Cwalina, Abrams), section 9.3:

> AVOID throwing an exception from within Dispose(bool) except under critical situations where the containing process has been corrupted.
>
> If Dispose could raise an exception, further finally block cleanup logic will not execute. To work around this, the user would need to wrap every call to Dispose (within their finally block!) in a try block, which leads to very complex cleanup handlers. If executing a Dispose(bool) method, never throw an exception if disposing is false.

Also from section 9.3:

> AVOID making types finalizable. Carefully consider any case in which you think a finalizer is needed. There is a real cost associated with instances with finalizers, from both a performance and code complexity standpoint."

Comment: I told you... :-)

Comment: @ZoharPeled I'm sorry for doubting you :)